# Is it possible to define a complex class at runtime in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Lets say I want to define the following model in Django:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Customer'
```

I know I can use `type` in Python to define classes. For example, the following class:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def printX(self):
        print self.x
```

Can be defined using:

```
def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

def printX(self):
    print self.x

Test = type('Test', (object,), {'__init__': __init__, 'printX': printX})
```

Now, Django models are basically classes, so theoretically this should be possible. However, I have a few questions:

- How do I define the inheritance from `models.Model`?
- How do I define the `age` field?
- How do I define the `Meta` and the attributes within it?

Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have already done everything you ask about. Inheritance: Replace the bases of ``(object,)`` as desired. Add ``age`` field and ``Meta`` nested class: Fields and nested classes are placed in a class just like methods, add them after ``printX``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Could you please write it out as an answer? I am really confused on how to do the Meta class part. Would that call the `type` method again?

Comment: But why would you do that for a model in Django? A model is supposed to correspond to a table in your db. How do you expect to do the migrations?

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't expect to do migrations. Thats why the model is non-managed. I have a database that I want to query using Django's ORM, but the class definition has to be in runtime due to other issues.

Comment: ok, then I don't really understand why you need to fabricate the model this way, but in any case, you can define `class Meta` at the same level as you do `def printX` and add it to the dictionary you pass to `type`. Same with `age`, define it with `age = IntegerField()` and add it to the dict.

Comment: Can you please clarify your constraints? Are you aware that all class definitions are evaluated at runtime? What makes you think you need to define the class using ˋtypeˋ explicitly? Whenever you can define a function using ˋdefˋ, you can also define a class using ˋclassˋ.